# Joomla Greeting Name to only show first word

Tags: php, string, joomla, word-count

In the Joomla (v3) logout form, it is showing the registered users full name they registered with.

```
echo JText::sprintf('MOD_LOGIN_HINAME', htmlspecialchars($user->get('name')));
```

**Rather than showing:**

Fred Bloggs

**I only want to show:**

Fred

What is the easiest way to edit the above to show just the first word from the ***$user->get('name')***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing anything, please don't override the file. Instead, create a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) so that when you update Joomla, your changes are not overridden.

Once done, you can use `strstr` which finds ehe first occurrence of a string, like so:

```
$name = strstr($user->get('name'), ' ', true);
echo JText::sprintf('MOD_LOGIN_HINAME', htmlspecialchars($name));
```